# Using LINQ. With two different lists. How can I identify objects that do not match

Tags: c#, linq

I have three classes:

```
public partial class Objective{
    public Objective() {
        this.ObjectiveDetails = new List<ObjectiveDetail>();
    }
    public int ObjectiveId { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ObjectiveDetail> ObjectiveDetails { get; set; }
}
public partial class ObjectiveDetail {
    public ObjectiveDetail() {
        this.SubTopics = new List<SubTopic>();
    }
    public int ObjectiveDetailId { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubTopic> SubTopics { get; set; }
}
public partial class SubTopic {
    public int SubTopicId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have two lists:

```
IList<ObjectiveDetail> oldObj;
IList<ObjectiveDetail> newObj;
```

The following LINQ gives me a new list of `ObjectiveDetail` objects where: the Number or the Text fields for any `ObjectiveDetail` object in the list differ between `oldObj` and `newObj`.

```
IList<ObjectiveDetail> upd = newObj
    .Where(wb => oldObj
        .Any(db => (db.ObjectiveDetailId == wb.ObjectiveDetailId) && 
                   (db.Number != wb.Number || !db.Text.Equals(wb.Text))))
     .ToList();
```

How can I modify this so the LINQ gives me a new list of `ObjectiveDetail` objects where: the Number or the Text fields **or the SubTopic collections** for any `ObjectiveDetail` object in the list differ between `oldObj` and `newObj`.

In other words I want an `ObjectiveDetail` to be added to the `upd` list if:

- It has Text in oldObj that's different from Text in newObj
- It has a Number in oldObj that's different from the Number in newObj
- It has a SubTopics collection with three elements in oldObj and 4 elements in newObj
- It has a SubTopics collection with no elements in oldObj and 2 elements in newObj
- It has a SubTopics collection with 2 elements in oldObj and no elements in newObj
- It has a SubTopics collection with elements with SubTopicId of 1 and 2 in oldObj and 1 and 3 in newObj

I hope someone can come up with just some additional line in the LINQ statement that I already have.

Comment: Are you looking for Enumerable.SequenceEquals? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes I think I need to have something like this but this might be more complex than needed. All I need is to compare the one field (subTopicId) of the subtopics array from the database with that from the front-end. If there's a difference I need this to add to the upd variable. Once there I will (next job) have to do some more processing of that.

Comment: What if it has a SubTopics collection with 2 elements in oldObj and 2 elements in newObj, but the content of of of the SubTopics is different. Has the ObjectiveDetail been changed in that case?

Comment: Is the count of the ObjectiveDetails oldObj and newObj always the same or is is possible to add new objects to newObj (that also must be saved)? And if no objects are added: Is the id of item with index x of objOld always the same as item with index x of objNew?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be what you need:

```
IList<ObjectiveDetail> upd = newObj.Where(wb =>
            oldObj.Any(db =>
                (db.ObjectiveDetailId == wb.ObjectiveDetailId) &&
                    (db.Number != wb.Number || !db.Text.Equals(wb.Text)
                    || db.SubTopics.Count != wb.SubTopics.Count
                    || !db.SubTopics.All(ds => wb.SubTopics.Any(ws =>
                                     ws.SubTopicId == ds.SubTopicId))
                    ))).ToList();
```

---

**How It Works**

`db.SubTopics.Count != wb.SubTopics.Count` confirms that the new object being compared (`wb`) and the old object being compared (`db`) have the same number of SubTopics. That part is pretty straightforward.

`!db.SubTopics.All(ds => wb.SubTopics.Any(ws => ws.SubTopicId == ds.SubTopicId))` is a bit more complicated. The `All()` method returns true if the given expression is true for all members of the set. The `Any()` method returns true if the given expression is true for any member of the set. Therefore the entire expression checks that for every SubTopic `ds` in the old object `db` there is a Subtopic `ws` with the same ID in the new object `wb`.

Basically, the second line ensures that every SubTopic present in the old object is also present in the new object. The first line ensures that the old & new objects have the same number of SubTopics; otherwise the second line would consider an old object with SubTopics 1 & 2 the same as a new object with SubTopics 1, 2, & 3.

---

**Caveats**

This addition will not check whether the SubTopics have the same `Name`; if you need to check that as well, change the `ws.SubTopicId == ds.SubTopicId` in the second line to `ws.SubTopicId == ds.SubTopicId && ws.Name.Equals(ds.Name)`.

This addition will not work properly if an ObjectiveDetail can contain more than one SubTopic with the same SubTopicId (that is, if SubTopicIds are not unique). If that's the case, you need to replace the second line with `!db.SubTopics.All(ds => db.SubTopics.Count(ds2 => ds2.SubTopicId == ds.SubTopicId) == wb.SubTopics.Count(ws => ws.SubTopicId == ds.SubTopicId))`. That will check that each SubTopicId appears exactly as many times in the new object as it does in the old object.

This addition will not check whether the SubTopics in the new object & the old object are in the same order. For that you would need to replace the 2nd line with `db.SubTopics.Where((ds, i) => ds.SubTopicId == wb.SubTopics[i].SubTopicId).Count != db.SubTopics.Count`. Note that this version also handles non-unique SubTopicId values. It confirms that the number of SubTopics in the old object such that the SubTopic in the same position in the new object is the same equals the total number of SubTopics in the old object (that is, that for every SubTopic in the old object, the SubTopic in the same position in the new object is the same).

---

**High Level Thoughts**

Konrad Kokosa's answer is better from a maintainability perspective (I've already upvoted it). I would only use a big ugly LINQ statement like this if you don't expect to need to revisit the statement very often. If you think the way you decide whether two `ObjectiveDetail` objects are equal might change, or the method that uses this statement might need to be reworked, or the method is critical enough that someone new to the code looking at it for the first time needs to be able to understand it quickly, then don't use a big long blob of LINQ.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this solution. It looks good. If you have some time can you explain just in a few lines how your answer works and reference your use of wb and ws. All that's needed is for you to explain the line you added. Thanks very much.

Comment: @SamanthaJ Edited with explanations, alternates if you need to it to check certain other things, and a nod to Konrad Kokosa.

Comment: I checked your code and it works fine. My application will only have 2-5 subtopics so speed is not an issue, they are unique so that's not an issue, they could appear in any order so that's not an issue. Your solution is simple, easy to understand and very clean. Thanks for the detailed explanation. I accepted your answer but I think you have to wait until the end of the bounty period before you get the points. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: The fact that code works is not the only necessary requirement - you [can read about it](http://blog.smartbear.com/process/your-code-may-work-but-it-still-might-suck/) from time to time everywhere. Although my answer was obviously only a draft, I believe it goes in better direction than this unmaintainable LINQ monster. Take someone (or even you after a year) and try to explain what it is doing...

Answer (score 7):

Instead of creating a huge and hard maintanable LINQ query that will try to find differences, I would create a list of the same objects within both list (intersection) and as a result, take sum of both collection except this intersection. To compare objects you can use `IEqualityComparer<>` implementation. Here is a draft:

```
public class ObjectiveDetailEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<ObjectiveDetail>
{
    public bool Equals(ObjectiveDetail x, ObjectiveDetail y)
    {
        // implemenation                          
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ObjectiveDetail obj)
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

and then simply:

```
var comparer = new ObjectiveDetailEqualityComparer();
var common = oldObj.Intersect(newObj, comparer);
var differs = oldObj.Concat(newObj).Except(common, comparer);
```

This will be much easier to maintain when classes change (new properties etc.).

Comment: This was my preferred solution.  Clean, easy to read, maintainable. +1

Comment: This solution has some serious problems that are only visible when you implement the Equals method. The solution simply don't work or the implentation of Equals() is not logical like x.ObjectiveDetailId != y.ObjectiveDetailId. Also it doesn't detect new added items (but it is unclear to me if the OP want that). **Could you implement the equals method?**

Answer (score 2):

Normally I would go with @Konrad Kokosa way. But it looks like you need a fast solution.

I tried it with some data. It gives the expected result. I am sure that you can modify the code for desired results.

```
var updatedObjects = oldObj.Join(newObj,
    x => x.ObjectiveDetailId,
    y => y.ObjectiveDetailId,
    (x, y) => new
    {
        UpdatedObject = y,
        IsUpdated = !x.Text.Equals(y.Text) || x.Number != y.Number //put here some more conditions
    })
    .Where(x => x.IsUpdated)
    .Select(x => x.UpdatedObject);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Problems**

Your LINQ query was not that bad but some proplems needed to be solved:

- Using `.Any()` in a `.Where()` means that the query is **much slower than needed**. This is because for every item in `objNew`, you iterate the items of `objOld`.
- `!db.Text.Equals(wb.Text)` throws an exception when `db.Text` is `null`.
- Your code doesn't detect new items added to `objNew` that doesn't exists in `objOld`. I don't know if that is a problem because you didn't told us if that is possible.

**Solution**

If you compare collections, it would be a good idea to override the Equals() and GetHashcode() methods:

```
public partial class ObjectiveDetail
{
    public ObjectiveDetail()
    {
        this.SubTopics = new List<SubTopic>();
    }
    public int ObjectiveDetailId { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubTopic> SubTopics { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(Object obj)
    {
        var typedObj = obj as ObjectiveDetail;
        return Equals(typedObj);
    }

    public bool Equals(ObjectiveDetail obj)
    {
        if ((object)obj == null) return false;

        return ObjectiveDetailId == obj.ObjectiveDetailId &&
               Number == obj.Number &&
               Text == obj.Text &&
               SubTopics != null && obj.SubTopics != null && // Just in the unlikely case the list is set to null
               SubTopics.Count == obj.SubTopics.Count;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return new { A = ObjectiveDetailId, B = Number, C = Text }.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then it is easy:

```
var dictionary = oldObj.ToDictionary(o => o.ObjectiveDetailId);

IList<ObjectiveDetail> upd = newObj
    .Where(n => !EqualsOld(n, dictionary))
    .ToList();
```

using this method:

```
private bool EqualsOld(ObjectiveDetail newItem, Dictionary<int, ObjectiveDetail> dictionary)
{
    ObjectiveDetail oldItem;
    var found = dictionary.TryGetValue(newItem.ObjectiveDetailId, out oldItem);
    if (!found) return false; // This item was added to the new list
    return oldItem.Equals(newItem);
}
```

Comment: I would also override Equals and GetHashCode for the SubTopic class, and compare them instead of simply comparing their count. But that is not a clear requirement from the question.

Comment: @Onots That is a logical next step but the OP didn't asked for that. But if this was a requirement, this is what I would do as well.

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right, you want to make a deep comparison between two .NET objects, regardless of LINQ. Why don't you use something like [comparenetobjects](http://comparenetobjects.codeplex.com/)?

Trying to implement a deep comparison through LINQ would probably be slower and more complex than making the comparison in the memory. Even if you chose to do it in LINQ realm, you would finally retrieve the whole object and perhaps you would do it with more than one queries, adding performance overhead. Therefore, I would suggest to **eagerly** load your data object from database and make the deep comparison without a specific linq query.

Hope I helped!

Comment: @Pantelie - I only have five objects to compare so speed is not an issue. The link you gave me looks interesting but seems like overkill. I know LINQ is very powerful and I am hoping to find a 1 line solution that I could add to my LINQ that I have already detecting the differences {except for subtopic).

Answer (score 1):

Find the entities that are not updated then exclude:

```
IEnumerable<ObjectiveDetail> newOds = ...;
IEnumerable<ObjectiveDetail> oldOds = ...;

// build collection of exclusions
// start with ObjectiveDetail entities that have the same properties
var propertiesMatched = oldOds.Join( newOds,
    o => new { o.ObjectiveDetailId, o.Number, o.Text },
    n => new { n.ObjectiveDetailId, n.Number, n.Text },
    ( o, n ) => new { Old = o, New = n } );

// take entities that matched properties and test for same collection
//  of SubTopic entities
var subTopicsMatched = propertiesMatched.Where( g =>
    // first check SubTopic count
    g.Old.SubTopics.Count == g.New.SubTopics.Count &&
    // match
    g.New.SubTopics.Select( nst => nst.SubTopicId )
        .Intersect( g.Old.SubTopics.Select( ost => ost.SubTopicId ) )
        .Count() == g.Old.SubTopics.Count )
    // select new ObjectiveDetail entities
    .Select( g => g.New );

// updated ObjectiveDetail entities are those not found
// in subTopicsMatched
var upd = newOds.Except( subTopicsMatched );
```

This would work w/ EF and run completely server-side if `newOds` and `oldOds` are `IQueryable<ObjectiveDetail>`s from a `DbContext`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried what you wanted but it is not too "neat" and it was not possible for me to make "one-liner-linq-expression" type code. Check it out and see if it is acceptable to you.

Also you need to check the performance but as you said there are not many objects so performance might not be of concern.

Also I have not tested it properly so if you wish to accept it then please do testing.

```
        var oldObj = _objectiveDetailService.GetObjectiveDetails(id);
        var newObj = objective.ObjectiveDetails.ToList();

        var upd = newObj
            .Where(wb => oldObj
                .Any(db => (db.ObjectiveDetailId == wb.ObjectiveDetailId) &&
                           (db.Number != wb.Number || !db.Text.Equals(wb.Text))))
             .ToList();

        newObj.ForEach(wb =>
        {
            var comOld = oldObj.Where(db => wb.ObjectiveDetailId == db.ObjectiveDetailId &&
                           db.Number == wb.Number && db.Text.Equals(wb.Text)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (comOld != null && wb.SubTopics.Any(wb2 => comOld.SubTopics.Where(oldST => wb2.SubTopicId == oldST.SubTopicId).Any(a => !a.Name.Equals(wb2.Name))))
            {
                upd.Add(wb);
            }
        });
```

You can write similar code to add and delete as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello samar. Can you rename some of the variables in your examples and start with these two lines: var oldObj = _objectiveDetailService.GetObjectiveDetails(id);
var newObj = objective.ObjectiveDetails.ToList(); What I am looking for is I think something like just this line: var upd = newObj
    .Where(wb => oldObj
        .Any(db => (db.ObjectiveDetailId == wb.ObjectiveDetailId) && 
                   (db.Number != wb.Number || !db.Text.Equals(wb.Text)))) with something added to that to do a check for changes to the subtopics array. Sorry if this is a bit unclear in the comment as unformatted.

Comment: Check updated answer but this will fail if "Number" and "Text" is different and "Name" inside SubTopic is same. You have to perform a new query for same "ObjectiveDetailId", "Number" and "Text" but different "Name" for same "ObjectiveDetailId". Should I update the answer as per my understanding?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't really understand any of your code. All I need to know at this point is which of the elements of oldObj and newObj are different. Currently I check for differences in text and name. Now I want to also check for differences in the SubTopics collections in each element. I was expecting something to be added to the existing .Any as here we compare the elements one by one. But you added on something after the .ToList(). I updated my question a bit to try and make it more clear. Thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer. As I said it is not possible for me to add something to "Any" method. I am not able to figure any such "1 line" solution. Check if the updated answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
IList<ObjectiveDetail> upd = newObj
    .Where(wb => oldObj
        .Any(db => (db.ObjectiveDetailId == wb.ObjectiveDetailId) && 
                   (db.Number != wb.Number || !db.Text.Equals(wb.Text)))


||!oldObj.Any(o=>o.DetailId == wb.DetailId) //check if it's there or a new one
       //check count
    || ((wb.SubTopics.Count!= oldObj.FirstOrDefault(o=>o.DetailId == wb.DetailId).SubTopics.Count 
     || //check Ids match, or you can add more properties with OR
       wb.SubTopics.Any(wbs=>oldObj.FirstOrDefault(o=>o.DetailId == wb.DetailId)
      .SubTopics.Any(obs=>obs.SubTopicId !=wbs.SubTopicId))))
      ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at below code. I created this function to compare two object then returns matched properties fields as an object.It may help full to you.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Compare two objects, returns destination object with matched properties, values. simply Reflection to automatically copy and compare properties of two object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source"></param>
    /// <param name="destination"></param>
    /// <returns>destination</returns>
    public static object CompareNameAndSync(object source, object destination)
    {
        Type stype = source.GetType();
        Type dtype = destination.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] spinfo = stype.GetProperties();
        PropertyInfo[] dpinfo = dtype.GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo des in dpinfo)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo sou in spinfo)
            {
                if (des.Name == sou.Name)
                {
                    des.SetValue(destination, sou.GetValue(source));
                }
            }
        }
        return destination;

    }
```