# How to use Entity Framework 6 to update many-to-many relationship?

Tags: entity-framework, orm

Someone else asked a similar question here: [How can I use EF6 to update a many to many table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21289340)

I mention that up front because I couldn't get any of the solutions given to work.

I also studied the solution give on Code Project: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/893609/CRUD-Many-to-Many-Entity-Framework, but this doesn't work for me either.

I'm trying to keep this as simple as possible.

I have two tables: dbo.Teacher and dbo.Student.  Each has an "ID" column that servers as a primary key.  I also have a third table called dbo.StudentTeacher which has exactly two columns, both are non-nullable and foreign keyed to the previous two tables; in other words, it establishes a many-to-many relationship between teachers and students.  As expected, the EDMX designed shows only dbo.Student and dbo.Teacher and infers the relationship between them.

[image]

Here is a script for the above; there is nothing else in the database.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Teacher
(
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(MAX)
);
CREATE TABLE dbo.Student
(
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(MAX)
);
CREATE TABLE dbo.TeacherStudent
(
    TeacherId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Teacher(Id),
    StudentId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Student(Id)
);
INSERT INTO Teacher(Id, Name)
VALUES
(101, 'Tom');
INSERT INTO Student(Id, Name)
VALUES
(201, 'Sue'),
(202, 'Stan');
INSERT INTO TeacherStudent(TeacherId, StudentId)
VALUES
(101, 201);
```

Now that I've established my data structures, I want to accomplish a very simple task.  From the script above, you can see that we have one teacher named "Tom" who has a student named "Sue".  We also have a student named "Stan" with no teacher.  My task is to modify the database so that Sue is no longer Tom's student and Stan becomes Tom's student.

To accomplish this, I wrote the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var entities = new TestEntities())
        {
            // There is only one teacher in the system.
            Teacher teacher = entities.Teachers.Single();
            // This teacher has a student #201: Sue.
            // I want to replace her with student #202: Stan.
            teacher.Students.Clear();
            teacher.Students.Add(new Student() { Id = 202 });
            entities.SaveChanges();
        }            
    }
}
```

It looks very simple: clear the students associated with Tom and then add Stan as Tom's student.  However, when I run the code, I get the following error: `Unable to update the EntitySet 'TeacherStudent' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <DeleteFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation.`

I tried simplifying the problem by trying to just remove Sue from being Tom's student without adding Stan, and I get the exact same error message.

As I understand, this error normally occurs when Entity Framework doesn't have enough information to do what you want it to do, but I really can't see what's missing.  There are two simple tables with a join table between them and I need to be able to change which rows are related to which other rows.

I should also note that if I'm not mistaken, the change that I wish to make in this example should affect only the dbo.TeacherStudent table; the other two tables should not be touched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after some more Google-Fu, I figured it out.

Even tho the join table must have only two columns with each column foreign keyed to the two tables to be related, the join table still needs a primary key, which can be a composite of the two foreign keys.

Thus, dbo.TeacherStudent should be created with this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TeacherStudent
(
    TeacherId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Teacher(Id),
    StudentId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Student(Id),
    PRIMARY KEY(TeacherId, StudentId)
);
```

Comment: For future reference a good way to see what EF is going to do is to create the relationship in EF and then get migrations to build the database for you. This will show you what EF is expecting (even if you arent actually using migrations for your actual db creation)